# Angular JS watch data from a service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

So I have a service that gets a json object which is working fine.  In my controller, I want to watch that object for any changes. When there is a change in the object, i want that to update on the fly in the UI.  Here is my service:

```
angular.module('vertopsappApp.services', [])
.factory('vertopsappAppAPIservice', function($http) {

var vertopsappAppAPI = {};

vertopsappAppAPI.getDrivers = function() {
  return $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: 'http://faboolis.com/example.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  });
}

return vertopsappAppAPI;
 });
```

My controller looks like this but I'm pretty sure its not the way to do this.

```
 .controller("LineCtrl", function ($scope, vertopsappAppAPIservice) {
   $scope.$watch('vertopsappAppAPIservice.getDrivers()', function (newVal) {
    console.log('data changes into: ', newVal)
   }, true);
 });
```

any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: the watch code doesn't make much sense. Where is the response data stored and used? It's wherever you store that data that you are probably wanting to pay attention to. Show more code relating to `getDrivers()`

Comment: $http service utilizes promises, you should [look at the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to see how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

You could try emitting an event from the service when your data changes, and listening to the same in your controller and hence update your model so that the UI changes.

**Edit with example**:

Inside Service when your data changes:

```
$rootScope.$emit("value_changed", newValue); //trigger this when you know there is a change in value
```

Inside controller:

`$rootScope.$on("value_changed", function(e,newValue) {
    $scope.urUIVariable = newValue;
});`

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?